# Firebase hosting cannot find my CSS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase hosting with firebase functions and firestore. Functions and firestore work as intended but hosting is not working as intended.

The issue that I am having is that my css and branding images are not showing up. They are not found by server. I have a functions directory and a public directory in the root directory of my project. If I move the public directory into the functions directory then serving locally works as intended and everything looks fine but then deploying throws an error saying that it cannot find the public directory.

It used to work just fine with the directory structure I have set up both locally and deployment.

Comment: No suggestions? What other information is needed? I followed the samples provided by firebase. This was working just fine in the past. This is the way that firebase says to set up the directory structure. What is the problem? I've seen that other people are having the same problem and no one is offering them help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing through the Firebase Slack community, I found the solution.

There is a problem with firebase-tools v4.1.0.

run the following command in your console/cmd:

```
npm i -g firebase-tools
```

this will update your firebase-tools to the latest version and deploying your hosting after that should fix the problem.

Comment: Tha k you very much for responding. I had done this earlier in the day and figured out that it did indeed fix the issue. I was behind on working on my site so I forgot to come back and close out my question.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve it. For future reference, just join the Firebase Slack community, people are much more willing to help you resolve your issues than on Stack Overflow, I'm sorry to say